# Как сделать автоматическое добавление в комбинированные списки?

Tags: python, list

Нужна помощь с частью кода переноса сочетания списков prices и items в список menu (как в примере). Буду очень благодарен за помощь

```
items = ["Arbuz = ", "Yabloko = ", "Morkovka = ", "Grusha = "] # товар

prices = [120.43, 10, 23.56, 92.41] #цена 

menu = [] # комбо цены и товар. (Пример - Arbuz = 120.43)


size = (len(prices))

combo = " "

for combo in range(size):

    combo = items[0:size] + prices[0:size] # попытки запихнуть prices + items в menu
    menu.append(combo)


def adder(item, price):

    items.append(item)  # Добавление товара
    prices.append(price)

adder("Moloko = ", 200)

print(menu)
```

Comment: на выходе должно быть арбуз - 120, яблоко 10, морковь - 23, груша - 92?

Comment: в идеале я хотел сделать так, что б в конечном результате оно показывало Арбуз - 120 рублей 43 копейки , Яблоко - 10 рублей и т.д. Но пока что сойдёт просто 120.43, 10, 23.56 и т.д.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
items = ["Arbuz", "Yabloko", "Morkovka", "Grusha"]
prices = [120.43, 10, 23.56, 92.41]

menu = []

for x, y in zip(items, prices):
    menu.append(f'{x} = {y}')

print('menu', menu)


>>> menu ['Arbuz = 120.43', 'Yabloko = 10', 'Morkovka = 23.56', 'Grusha = 92.41']


def add(item, price, menu_1):
    menu_1.append(f'{item} = {price}')
    return menu_1


print('add', add('salad', 234, menu))

>>> menu ['Arbuz = 120.43', 'Yabloko = 10', 'Morkovka = 23.56', 'Grusha = 92.41']
add ['Arbuz = 120.43', 'Yabloko = 10', 'Morkovka = 23.56', 'Grusha = 92.41', 'salad = 234']
```

[zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

> в идеале я хотел сделать так, что б в конечном результате оно
> показывало Арбуз - 120 рублей 43 копейки , Яблоко - 10 рублей и т.д.

```
items = ["Arbuz", "Yabloko", "Morkovka", "Grusha"]
prices = [120.43, 10, 23.56, 92.41]

menu = []

for x, y in zip(items, prices):
    if isinstance(y, int):
        menu.append(f'{x} = {y} руб.')
    elif isinstance(y, float):
        menu.append(f'{x} = {str(y).split(".")[0]} руб. {str(y).split(".")[1]} коп.')


print('menu', menu)
>>> menu ['Arbuz = 120 руб. 43 коп.', 'Yabloko = 10 руб.', 'Morkovka = 23 руб. 56 коп.', 'Grusha = 92 руб. 41 коп.']
```

[isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)

Comment: Отлично! Вот только не хватает функции с добавлением продукта и цены в листы.

Comment: ну добавьте сами, она же есть у вас в вопросе, так же если ответ является решением, отметьте его таковым это поможет другим участникам.

Comment: обновил ответ - как и просили

Comment: Большое вам спасибо !!!

Comment: В `add` у вас не очень красиво - работаете с `menu_1`, а возвращаете `menu`, должно быть какое-то единообразие - либо вы знаете о внешних для функции переменных, либо нет (лучше, когда нет).

Comment: @CrazyElf буду рад совету как это привести в более красивый вид.

Comment: @Sasha я добавил код для отображения рублей и копеек, см. после цитаты.

Comment: @Violet Возвращайте из `add` всё-таки `return menu_1`, вроде это и одно и то же, но в идеале функция должна знать только переменные, которые ей в явном виде переданы, а это `menu_1`, про `menu` функция ничего не должна знать. Вдруг ему поменяют имя снаружи - и эта функция тогда сломается.

Comment: @Violet Круто! Но вот только перевод в рубли и копейки не работает с ценами ново-созданных товаров.

Comment: Потому что нужно изменить функцию добавления так же как это сделано в цикле.

Answer (score 3):

Можно объединить исходные списки через `zip()` в список меню, а потом к нему добавлять пункты меню.

```
items = ["Arbuz = ", "Yabloko = ", "Morkovka = ", "Grusha = "]
prices = [120.43, 10, 23.56, 92.41]

menu = list(zip(items, prices))

def adder(combo: list, item: str, price: float):
    menu.append(tuple([item, price]))

adder(menu, "Moloko = ", 200)

print(menu)
```

Но вообще лучше сделать либо через словарь, либо заморочиться с классом. Ниже вариант через словарь:

```
menu = {i: p for i, p in zip(items, prices)}

menu["Moloko"] = 200.0
menu["Sok"] = 15.0
print(menu)  # {'Arbuz': 120.43, 'Yabloko': 10, 'Morkovka': 23.56, 'Grusha': 92.41, 'Moloko': 200.0, 'Sok': 15.0}
```

Comment: постоянно я про list забываю. правда при таком решении будет список содержащий `tuple`

Comment: Да тут вообще лучше через словарь делать)

Answer (score 1):

```
c = []
for i in range(len(items)):
    c.append(items[i] + str(prices[i]))
print(c)
```

Неизящный императивный способ без zip